# Flutter/Dart Error: 'Account' Type Not Recognized as a Valid Type Argument

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, appwrite

I have this error in my code under the <model.account>

THE ERROR :

```
 The name 'Account' isn't a type, so it can't be used as a type argument.
    Try correcting the name to an existing type, or defining a type named 'Account'.
```

THE CODE :

```
import 'package:appwrite/appwrite.dart';
import 'package:appwrite/models.dart' as model;
import 'package:fpdart/fpdart.dart';
import 'package:appname/core/core.dart';

// want to singup, want to get user account -> Account 
// want to access user related data -> model.Account 

abstract class IAUTHAPI {
 FutureEither<model.Account>signUp({
    required String email,
    required String password,
  });
}
```

please make sure to read the notes above I have to use model.Account not Account because :

> // want to singup, want to get user account -> Account

> // want to access user related data -> model.Account

I don't know you I have this error I am watching video and the person in video did same and donot have any error. thank you for reading if you know what should I do help me !

Answer (score 2):

From the official package's [changelog](https://pub.dev/packages/appwrite/changelog#900), seems like the `Account` model has changed its name into `User` since version `9.0.0`. So you should use it like this instead:

```dart
abstract class IAUTHAPI {
 FutureEither<model.User> signUp({
    required String email,
    required String password,
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm new to the tech world, and I'm not sure how to check for updates yet. Yes, the "user" worked <3

Answer (score 0):

According to Appwrite updates, above 9.0.0 version Account has been replaced with User,

you can now use it as;

```
models.User
```

instead of

```
models.Account
```